# Site redirects to index.php without www

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I am trying to verify my SSL certificate for my website.
So I did upload a file to my server but when I try to access the file it is only working when i enter the url with `www` when I do it without `www` it redirects me to the index of my wordpress page.

Here is the url which redirects to index.php without the `www`
http://vanloonautobedrijf.nl/.well-known/pki-validation/3619BF0D6B387464A49478D183780BF0.txt

I did empty my htaccess file and still cant reach it without `www`

Comment: This redirect might be configured at a higher “level” - go check your server configuration/hosting panel in that regard.

Comment: You should clear your browser cache when you update your `.htaccess` file as the browser will cache the responses given from the file

Comment: @Martin but when you remove www. it is not working

Comment: see @CBroe's comment above

Answer (score 0):

You have a redirection (301) configured somewhere which redirects all non-www requests to the same URL (see attached screenshot). In your case, it's not what you need, because the path info + query string is lost during that redirection.

[image]

When you find where is your redirection defined, try fixing it by setting the option to keep the path/query from the original URLs. The exact method to achieve this is specific to the way the redirection was implemented.

If you find where your redirection was configured, update your question and we might be able to help you fix it.